# Changing data types within a list of lists

Tags: python

I have a list of 50 lists each sub-list has 5 elements. What I want to do is take the 2nd element and change it from a string into an integer for 49 of the lists.

```
for i in range(len(Data)):
    Data[i] = Data[i].strip()
    Data[i] = Data[i].split(',')
    Data[i] = int(x) for x in Data[[1:][1]]
```

In my mind this should start with element 2 of the main list and then change element 1 into an integer for all the lists. Hints the range 1:

But obviously this is not working

Each list inside the list has an element 0 a state name and element 1 state population. I want to sum the state populations. But first I need to switch the population figure from a string to an integer.

First element of the list is:

[['Alabama', '4802982']

I want to change '4802982' to an integer. So I can use the sum function. And sum the rest of the 49 states (each following list)

Comment: Aside from brackets missing from the list comprehension on the last line, you're not assigning things at all.

Comment: Please add a short example of the input and expected output to your question.

Answer (score 1):

As you are trying to convert `string` to `int` only second element of list of list you can try this way.

```
# From your question I assume your data will be like
Data = [["list-1", "1", "something"], ["list-2", "2", "something else"]]
updated_data = []
for d in Data:
    d[1] = int(d[1])
    updated_data.append(d)

print(updated_data)
```

**Output:** `[['list-1', 1, 'something'], ['list-2', 2, 'something else']]`

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
Data[i] = [int(x) for x in Data[i]]
```

Comment: Right but I don't want to change every element in list. Just the 2nd element in each of the 49 lists.

Answer (score 0):

It's a good idea to make the data conversion a function of its own that works on a single "row" or "line":

```
def map_line(line):
    line = line.strip().split(',')
    return line[0] + [int(x) for x in line[1:]]

for i in range(len(Data)):
    Data[i] = map_line(Data[i])
```